# ColdFusion session variables not setting correctly

Tags: coldfusion

I have a few session variables I need setup for permissions and only the userID, userName and sessionAdmin variables are making it through. I do a cfdump and see all of the variables set to 0, which is the cfparam default. I also can not get the page to redirect to my sample address.

login.cfm

```
<cfif isDefined("FORM.login")>
  <cfset Encryptpwd = Encrypt(FORM.password, application.PsswrdKy)>
  <cfset loginInfo = CFCmain.getLogin(FORM.username,Encryptpwd)>
  <cflock timeout=20 scope="session" type="exclusive">
    <cfset session.UserName = loginInfo.username>
    <cfset session.userid = loginInfo.id>
    <cfset session.Access_admin = loginInfo.superadmin>
    <cfset session.Access_var1 = loginInfo.var1>
    <cfset session.Access_var2 = loginInfo.var2>
    <cfset session.Access_var3 = loginInfo.var3>
    <cfset session.Access_var4= loginInfo.var4>
    <cfset session.Access_agency = loginInfo.agency>
  </cflock>
  <cflocation url="http://www.google.com">
</cfif>
```

and main.cfc where my variables are pulled from the db

```
<cffunction name= "getLogin" access="remote" returntype="any" >
  <cfargument name="uname" type="string">
  <cfargument name="pwd" type="string">
  <cfquery name="getdata" datasource="#application.db#">
    select * from users2 where username = '#arguments.uname#' and password = '#arguments.pwd#'
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn getdata>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: What do you see for those fields when you dump the getdata query?  Also, not related to your question, but query parameters are your freinds.

Comment: I have cfparam setting all variables to default 0 on the main page. When I dump var1, var2, var3, and var4 are all 0. superadmin is the only that is set to 1. In my database the user has all permissions set to 1. I have never used cfqueryparam

Comment: Like Dan inquires, do a `<cfdump var="#loginInfo#">` immediately before the cflock and screenshot that and paste it here.

Comment: unrelated to your actual question, but it's a bad idea for your `getLogin` method to have an access type of `remote`. You want to set that to `public` to restrict the access to it unless you explicitly what to make it accessible directly (public is accessible to your application, remote is accessible to the world), and as others have said use `cfqueryparam` :)

Comment: How about changing the cflocation to go to a page that dumps your session scope?  And maybe a line or two of your cfparam, it's difficult to figure out where that fits in here.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear on `<cfqueryparam>`. In any case, you should not store the encrypted password of the user in the database. You should not store the user's password *at all*. If you must store something, store a salted cryptographic hash. Also, instead of `session.Access_x` use role based security (see `<cfloginuser>`).

Comment: Recommended reading on password hashing: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm. If you store an encrypted password in the database and the encryption key is hard coded into your application -- like in your code sample -- then this is actually *not any better than storing clear text passwords*. Seriously, don't do that.

Comment: Check whether FORM.login is defined. Better use <cfqueryparam> in <cfquery>.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like the variable FORM.login is not defined!?
try:

```
<cfif isDefined("FORM.login")>
    <cfdump var="hello">
    <cfabort>
    ....
```

if you don't see the "hello", FORM.login is not defined...

try also:

```
<cfdump var="#form#" abort>
```

to see what is defined in the form scope.

And how others said, use cfqueryparam!! (security)

```
<cfquery name="getdata" datasource="#application.db#">
    select * 
    from users2 
    where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.uname#">
    and password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.pwd#">
</cfquery>
```